# workstation multi-robot with rviz

Tags: rviz, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there !

We've got a problem ( my classmate and I) about the multi-robot supervision on Rviz. We would like to see 2 turtlebots on the workstation Rviz but we don't know if we have to do a .launch file where turtlebot commands and names are but we aren't sure. We think ROS_NAMESPACE could make a mistake on the network when we're trying to put 2 turtlebots on Rviz.
For the moment, we use :
roscore on the workstation.
ROS_NAMESPACE=turtlebotX roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch for each turtlebot, where X is a letter about a turtlebot ( turtlebotA, turtlebotB).
ROS_NAMESPACE=turtlebotX roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch for each turtlebot.
After this command, we've got a problem with warning flood on each prompt of turtlebot computer. They seems to be a warning about tf_old_data on the turtlebotB only.

roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch
The workstation can control one of them but only if they're not connected at the same time on it. If A and B are connected, the workstation only see on Rviz the same turtlebot( in ur case, A). So maybe it's about alphabetical order and the workstation always store turtlebotA.
We can see the turtlebot's camera and we can move it with teleop keyboard command.
So, the real questions are : need a .launch? if yes, what kind of information do we write inside?
does we make a mistake with command or forgot useful command to do?

Thanks for listening.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202997/workstation-multi-robot-with-rviz/) by [florian2](https://answers.ros.org/users/21623/florian2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We found the real problem thank to you. It was about the school's proxy who blocked port 123 allowing the update of time.
The new problem is about Rviz and more precisely 'odom'. We have always 2 turtlebots connected on the workstation and we want to see both on Rviz but we don't know how to see them correctly. For the moment, Rviz get information of two turtlebots and think they are the same robot. Does we have to make launch and how exactly just for a example of 2 turtlebots? tf_frames could be one of the problem too?

---

Originally posted by [florian2](https://answers.ros.org/users/21623/florian2/) with karma: 16 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0